# How does awk evaluate logical operations?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a pretty simple awk script which looks like this:

```
awk < file \
        ' { 
                variable = $1
          }
                variable == 0 && system("do_some_sql_statement")!=0 \
          {
                print variable
          } '
```

Because of performance reasons I want to make sure that my sql statement will only be called when my first condition is true. On my machine this is indeed the case, but can I be sure that this will also be the case if someone else runs this on a different OS? Does it depend on the OS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Boolean-Ops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Etan Raisner pointed out, the answer can be found here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Boolean-Ops

> `boolean1 && boolean2`
>   ...
>   The subexpression `boolean2` is evaluated only if
>   `boolean1` is true.